# Update editor of published version without affecting version number - CSOM

Tags: client-object-model, csom, metadata, versioning

I am trying to copy files from one site collection to another including their version history and preserve the metadata using **CSOM**. I am almost there using the below logic for each version of the file. However I am not able to get this to work for major/published/X.0 versions.

1) Check out existing file (If not first version uploaded)

2) Upload the file version

3) Assign the document metadata and perform a checkin (either major or minor to match original files version history).

4) Use ValidateUpdateListItem to set the Editor and Modified values as they were overwritten by the checkin in step 3

This works in most scenarios and keeps the modified date. However if the version was a published version and minor versions are enabled this creates a new X.1 version.

Does anyone have a way of updating the Editor for a published version with minor versions enabled on the list that does not affect the version number? The only solutions I have found require server side code or temporarily disabling versioning which I cannot do!

Requirements:

CSOM only - this is client side C# code.

I cannot temporarily enable/disable versioning or minor versions on the library.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest CSOM dll from nuget(minimum 16.1.5626.1200 or above). In that, the `SystemUpdate` method has been added.

After referencing that dll in your project, in your CSOM code, instead of `listItem.Update()` use `listItem.SystemUpdate()`.

It allows you to update a list item without changing modification date, author, publishing and versioning information.

Reference - [SharePoint CSOM August 2016 update](https://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-august-2016-updated)

Comment: I have given this a go and it does now set the Editor correctly without incrementing the version. However it is not saving the modified date I set. Ths means the versions show as modified when I checked them in instead of their original modified dates. Am I missing something? Also is there any way of doing this with SharePoint 2013 as it does not have this method? Thanks!